# ActiveRecord query, adding inner join, but getting syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having trouble adding an association to some existing code.

This works:

> PropertySpa.joins(:spa_results, :country)

and this works:

> PropertySpa.joins(:spa_results => [:comp_status])

but combining it all to get what I want doesn't work:

> PropertySpa.joins(:spa_results => [:comp_status], :country)

gives me error:

> SyntaxError: (irb):18: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
>     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in
>   `start'   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`
>   start'   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in
>   `console ...

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you try `PropertySpa.joins([{ :spa_results => [:comp_status] }, :country)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
PropertySpa.joins(:country, :spa_results => [:comp_status])
```

Most methods are written to expect implicit hashes to be the last arguments of a method.

Comment: Thank you, I think that was it.